# Image not filling background container

Tags: html, css, image, background

Im trying to make an opening page for an app but my responsive image will not fit the full screen. Ive tried using the property values for background-size: yet the problem is still persisting. Using container, it cut the width of the image and some was missing and i dont want that.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the image im using - http://www.shbarcelona.cat/blog/cat/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/formula-2.jpg

Thank You.

```
 <html>

 <head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/theme-classic/theme-classic.css"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


 </head><body>
 <div data-role="page" >
    <div id="background_image">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Formula 1 Team List</h1>
        </div>


        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="index_button">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-ajax="false"> List of Teams </a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
            <h1> Kevin Murphy - 11139323</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#background_image
{
background: transparent url(formula1.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat ;
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: I have and the image is still too short, its a large image 1280 × 1024 so i dont understan why it shouldnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `background-size: cover` to make a full-width image. They key here is ensuring you set the height and width of the div and body/html to 100%.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#something {
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background: url(https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1426200830301-372615e4ac54) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/soxjt0aj/2/

Comment: I still seem to have the problem when I use this code, the image still isnt filling the page height wise, and the image is going over the edges now aswell

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle? Or provide a site link?

Comment: I updated the code in your fiddle to make the image work: https://jsfiddle.net/shaansingh/m0hga36c/2/